# Pandas groupby rollup

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a data frame as this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,2],"B":["a","b","c"],"metric":[4,5,2]})
df=df.groupby(["A","B"]).sum()
```

The resulting df is:

```
     metric
A B        
1 a       4
  b       5
2 c       2
```

of course with multiindex levels A and B.

How could I "roll up" sum of metric up to A level and apply it to df across just that level, so that I'd get sth like:

```
     metric   total_metric_by_A
A B        
1 a       4                   9
  b       5                   9
2 c       2                   2
```

I know I could reset index, group by A only and then somehow join back, but I really don't want to do that. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

groupby also accepts a level parameter so you can do something like:

```
df.groupby(level='A').transform('sum')
Out: 
     metric
A B        
1 a       9
  b       9
2 c       2
```

You need to assign this back of course

```
df['total_metric_by_A'] = df.groupby(level='A').transform('sum')

df
Out: 
     metric  total_metric_by_A
A B                           
1 a       4                  9
  b       5                  9
2 c       2                  2
```

Answer (score 2):

`reindex` without 2nd `groupby`

```
df['Total']=df.sum(level='A').reindex(df.index,level=0)
df
Out[179]: 
     metric  Total
A B               
1 a       4      9
  b       5      9
2 c       2      2
```